# Merge .NET config files based on environment in Visual Studio / MS Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, app-config

I have a .NET application which is supposed to run in multiple environments for eg. DEV, PROD. I have several config files like COMMON.config, app.config, DEV.config, PROD.config, etc.

For Development environment I want to merge app.config, COMMON.config and DEV.config.

For Production environment I want to merge app.config, COMMON.config and PROD.config.

Is there a way to achieve this via pre/post build events ?

Most of the information available online are for web.config.

Comment: Maybe keep one config file with multiple config sections?

Comment: Single config file can become huge and unmanageable if it will grow larger over time.

Comment: See if this ( http://12factor.net/config ) is of any help.

Comment: Just a thought, I know it may not be what you are looking for, but I had a similar "config maintenance" issue of several environments. What I eventually did, and was the best for me, was to keep the configuration settings in the database, and develop a module that will handle it. It makes maintenance easier, I even think that in runtime retrieving values was in better performance, since I cached it (in memory). Anyway, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found useful information at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27178/Config-Customization-at-Build-Time-in-Visual-Studi

It used build events to make call to a small program that does the merging.